# do SOAP requests in loop with Derrefered

Tags: jquery, ajax, soap

I want to do something like in this article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1073543/Waiting-for-Promises-in-a-Loop (Run the Promises In Order (Not In Parallel)) and I want to use it to call soap with ajax, but I don´t want to do it in order. I want to do it so when any of results will come I will display it on it´s place. So for example I have 5 products and foreach I will call soap to calculate their price. When any of them returns price I want to display it in it´s div.